Speedybee405v3 usb communication with msp_rx
I'm trying to get the flight controller 405speedybeev3 to communicate through USB using Python multiwii. I have the receiver set to msp_rx, but I can't get the IMU data to appear.
When I plug the USB into the computer, and use multiwii.py, it should get the IMU data, but the flight controller doesn’t show any values.
